# create new column based another using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to populate a new column in a dataframe but I am receiving this error:

```
process.py:27: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
sample of dataframe:
    countem
    2
    3
    3
    2
    9
    4
    5
weights = 
{'2':'0.5','3':'0.6','4':'0.6','5':'0.7','6':'0.7','7':'0.8','8':'0.8','9':'0.9'}
manif = merch.loc[merch['countem'] >= 2].reset_index()
manif['weight'] = manif['countem'].map(weights)
```

Every example I have found searching states to do it this way.

Comment: Did you filter `manif` and assign the filtered frame back to the variable `manif` before using map? Because, currently, it is not reproducible.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I updated the code above. I pulled on a criteria to get `manif` from a larger df but did not do `.reset_index()`. That solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Filtering a DataFrame creates a slice of that larger frame. Create a copy of it and that will take care of the waring - e.g., `manif = merch.loc[merch['countem'] >= 2].copy()`